# Execute another UIGestureRecognizer directly after another UIGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIScrollView` with 2 `UIGestureRecognizers'`, 1 `LongPress` and one `Pan`.

What I want to happen is that the user `LongPresses` and after its `StateBegan` the `Pan` should kick in.

What actually happens: The user `LongPresses` -> have to release and then touch screen again to use the `Pan` recognizer.

Is there a way to cancel the LongPress after its StateBegan? or am I forced to make my own custom Recognizer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. A gesture can wait for another to fail, but this won't work in your case Create your own gesture recognizer.